# How do I selectively purge MySQL table rows using a list of column values?

Tags: mysql

I am new to databases and working with MySQL. I have a large MySQL table with the following columns: `Id`, `Link`, `Timestamp`.

And I have a list of links. I want to keep only the rows with link column that matches an entry in this list.

Any pointers to how I accomplish this?

Comment: How long is that list compared to the number of rows in your table? Is this something you want to do once, or regularly?

Comment: are you looking for a DELETE statement?

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM MyBigUberTable WHERE Link NOT IN (...);
```

That should do it. Just replace the ellipsis with a comma-separated list of of Link values (or a SELECT statement that produces said list).

Comment: This will do it, but fair warning that this will be very slow depending on what OP's definition of 'large' is.